# Creating a filling animation on transparent image in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

Given a div that has an image in its background, if **this image is transparent** (this is an important detail), how can I change its color? Is it possible?

### HTML

```
<body>
    <div>
        <hr/>
        <div id ='imagediv' class="ornament"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

### CSS

```
body {
margin-top: 100px; 
background: url('http://hostmypicture.com/images/fundokairo.png') repeat;
}

hr {
    height: 30px;
    color: #578daf;
    background: url('http://hostmypicture.com/images/barrapreta.png') repeat-x 0 50%;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 9px 0 0 0;
}

.ornament {
    width: 169px;
    height: 169px;
    background: url('http://s23.postimg.org/6prq112g7/mascara_Fundo_Branco_Kairos.png') 0 50%;
    margin: -104px auto 0 auto;
}
```

`ornament` is the class of the div.

### JavaScript

```
var divImage = document.getElementById('imagediv');
var divStyle = divImage.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(divImage, false);
var divBackImage = divStyle.backgroundImage;
```

How can the image be filled?

---

I tried without success to fill the image using `fillStyle` and `fill()` of JavaScript. But it seems that using `canvas` is a possibility.

---

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9EFdF/21/

Note: I want the effect of a progress bar, so the color needs to come from underside.

Comment: I would be curious to see what you have actualy tried before asking here. You JSFiddle just shows a setup, you never talked about what you tried to fulfill the animation.

Comment: @JeffNoel I tried without success to fill the image using fillStyle and fill() of JavaScript.

Comment: @JeffNoel Well noticed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply set a new style for the element like this - note: it will be the *transparent* parts of the image that will change so in this case if you want the inner part to change color change transparency so that part is transparent:

```
imagediv.style.backgroundColor = '#000'; //new color
```

You can chose to use `getElementById` first, however, elements that has an ID can be referenced directly, but for example's sake:

```
var el = document.getElementById('imagediv');
el.style.backgroundColor = '#000'; //new color
```

<kbd>**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/9EFdF/22/)**</kbd>

If you want to keep the image as-is and fill it's inner part the only other option is to use canvas and its composite modes.

Comment: "If you want to keep the image as-is and fill it's inner part the only other option is to use canvas and its composite modes." This is exactly what I need. I will try to use canvas so.

Comment: @felipe.zkn how did it go?

Answer (score 1):

If the div is the same size as the background image, you could add a `background-color` style to the div and the colour would show through the transparent image.

Comment: Please reformulate this question as an answer or place it as a comment on the question and remove it as an answer.